# $result is not a resource SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, row

I am selecting values from a row, and inserting it into a table.

**Receiving the error:** mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on **line 42**.

```
35 <?php
36 // Viewing input values from its respected row
37 $query = "SELECT * FROM servers";
38 $result = mysql_query($query);
39
40 echo "<table"; 
41
42 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
43 echo "<tr><td>" . $row['serverip'] . "</td><td>" ;
44
45 echo "</table>"; 
46
47 mysqli_close();
48
49 }
50 ?>
```

I am told that this error is caused because $result is not a resource.. however I have configured $result in **line 38**. Any ideas as to whats causing the error?

Comment: Did you try checking for errors after the `mysql_query`?

Comment: youi connect to db some where?

Comment: echo mysql error description and code after line # 38 like, echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link); and see what error you got

Comment: `mysql_query` returns a resource on success, and (as is your case) `false` on errors such as invalid query, no table, no permission to access the table or no DB connection. That said, do not use `mysql_*` functions in new code. They're deprecated and support for them is going be removed from PHP in the future.

Comment: Try mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); Btw, you should close your table tag, and why is that td at the end of your echo statement (line 43) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of issues at play here.

First off do not use MySQL it is deprecated use MySQLi isntead

Second rewrite your code as detailed here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

You need to define the DB connection in a variable

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Next store your query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM servers";
```

echo your HTML

```
 echo "<table>"; //added the closing ">" as you left it out.
```

Next Create an If statement to run the query against the DB in.

```
 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
```

Then add your while loop

```
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Add your table rows

```
          echo "<tr><td>" . $row['serverip'] . "</td></tr>" ; //changed </td> to </tr>
```

Close the While loop

```
     }
```

Free your result set

```
     mysqli_free_result($result);
```

close if statement

```
 }
```

Add error catching else statement

```
 else {

      printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));

 }
```

close DB connection

```
 mysqli_close($link);
```

echo your closing HTML

```
 echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

please try following code:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

Comment: there is no way this is answers the question